# ngFor is not working despite having CommonModule imported in the existing module

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-modules

**ngFor** is not working in my code. I have the following code structure.

1. AppModule - contains App Component with router-outlet
2. HomeModule - contains Home Component - uses **ngFor**. (ngFor works here with no issues)
3. TestModule - contains Test Module - uses ngFor (ngFor does not work here)

I already have "**BrowserModule**" import in the AppModule.
I also have "**CommonModule**" import in both **HomeModule** and TestModule

I have this code in **HomeModule** **home.component.html** file (Works as expected)

```html
<mat-card [class]="(selected_test.id === test.id)? 'test-card selected': 'test-card'" *ngFor="let test of tests" (click)="selectCard($event, test)">

  <div class="left">
    <div class="title">{{test.title}}</div>
    <div class="description">{{test.description}}</div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="question-count">{{test.questions.length}} Question{{(test.questions.length > 1?'s':'')}}</div>
  </div>

</mat-card>
```

I have this code in **TestModule** *test.component.html*:

```html
<div *ngFor="let q of test.questions" class="question-item">
  <div class="question-title">{{q.prompt}}</div>
  <div class="question-options">
    <!-- <div *ngFor="let option of question.options" class="question-option">{{option}}</div> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Code in snippet 1 works while the code in snippet 2 does not work. I am not sure what is going on with this.

Edit:

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar'
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { HomeModule } from './pages/home/home.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**home.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'
import { MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  exports:[
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

**test.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [TestComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    TestComponent
  ]
})
export class TestModule { }
```

Comment: Couple questions: are there any other errors at the top of the `ng serve` log, and are these modules lazy loaded or using a shared module?

Comment: this first you use `tests` and the second you use `test` - are you sure you are providing a single test object in the `TestModule`?

Comment: Can you confirm whether `test.questions` holding the array or not?

Comment: @NathanBeck - There are no other errors, neither in the terminal nor in browser. These modules are just being loaded using a router outlet. Currently there is no lazy loading

Comment: @RandyCasburn - HomeModule is rendering the titles for multiple tests, that is why is a plural. In the TestModule, I am only passing a single test.

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti - I have already tried logging the output in ngOnInit() and it shows the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of imports in the `appModule`. Make the `BrowserModule` as the first import.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    AppRoutingModule,   
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule    
  ],
```

Comment: BroswerModule is already the first import.

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda late but I got the same issue and find out how to solve it.

My component's module was never imported (directly or indirectly) in my `AppModule` where `BrowserModule` was imported. Then it would not have `ngFor` directive declared.

In other words, your `TestModule` must be in `AppModule`'s imports list :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, ..., TestModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Or your module must be imported in one of your other module that is already imported in `AppModule` :

```
AppModule [imports] AnyModule(s) [imports] TestModule
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i was lazy loading my featureModule while it is not imported to the HomeModule.